# SC2 statistics by player like WC3 does it?

Tags: starcraft-2, warcraft-3-the-frozen-throne, warcraft-3

In WC3 TFT when you're doing ladder, you can view a lot of statistics online, e.g:

http://classic.battle.net/war3/ladder/w3xp-player-stats.aspx?Gateway=Azeroth&PlayerName=Jorgie

I've been trying to find the similar information for SC2 but the most I can see is a basic match history and the # of wins, am I missing something? It would be nice to view a detailed statistical information about your profile.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SC2 Ranks](http://sc2ranks.com) has a match history, and can also show win percentage by map, but I believe they skim off the Battle.Net API, so it won't be any more than Blizzard provides in the first place.

If you want more information about *your own* matches, [SC2 Gears](https://sites.google.com/site/sc2gears/) can look through all your past replays and give you much more information.  What it can do is too extensive to list here, check out their [features page](https://sites.google.com/site/sc2gears/features/replay-analyzer).

Comment: Just found SC2 gears, it is rather good :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [sc2drill](http://sc2drill.com)

[image: graphic]

You can filter by matchup/type and team size too.